# mysql STR_TO_DATE function

Tags: mysql

I would like to convert MySQL string to required date format .

I have below lines in a file.

```
30-06-2017,clarke
31-07-2018,warner
```

my table is having 2 columns .

```
Column1 datatype :: date
Column2 datatype :: varchar(30)
```

I have executed below query

```
load data local infile 'test.txt' into table sample fields terminated by ',' set column1=str_to_date(@c1,'%d-%m-%Y') ;
```

Column1 data was not loaded and I got below warnings.

> Data wad truncated for *column1* at *row1*

May I know what is wrong in the sql query which I am using ?

Comment: date format for mysql is YYYY-MM-DD while you have DD-MM-YYYY. Your query fails for that

Comment: I am trying to set the date format in the query . But it's not taking where as I have tried by changing data type from date to varchar . after chaning data type I am able to load the data successfully .

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the columns `(@c1, @c2)` from the file. Following command works fine.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'test.txt' INTO TABLE sample FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (@c1, @c2) SET column1=STR_TO_DATE(@c1,'%d-%m-%Y'), column2=@c2;
```

Comment: Thank you .This is working fine .But ,If we have 30 columns we have to set the value for 30 columns like set c1=STR_TO_DATE(@c1,'%d-%m-%Y'),c2=@c2,c3=@c3,.....c30=@c30..This will be complex . Is there any alternative or shortcut we have to directly to set mysql date format for a particular column .

Comment: What if sometimes you have more fields in the table but you want to import for particular fields? That time you have to choose the fields. So if you want to import less fields or customize the data, you should mention the fields.

Comment: Yeah I understand your point ..But , If I  want to to load a  file which is having 30 fields (I need 30 columns data) then I have to set 30 columns in load query . Instead of setting one  column for mysql date format , I have to set all columns which makes query a little complex .

Comment: Yeah that's bit of complex one. You can simplify the import process if you do the import with little bit of coding. First import the data to temp table. Retrieve the data from temp data then process and save it in the actual table.

Comment: Okay . Thank you.